# spawned robot in Gazebo is moving by itself (Moveit!)

Tags: ros, gazebo, rviz, moveit, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

This is my first question, so please have some understanding if I haven't posted it like it was meant to be posted.
I am running Ubuntu 18.04.2 with ROS_Melodic and Gazebo 9, I have also installed Moveit! package like it was explained in the [moveit tutorial](https://moveit.ros.org/install/), after that I have made catkin package and in the src folder I have git cloned [the fanuc moveit! package](https://github.com/ros-industrial/fanuc)`(Kinetic distro)` and all dependent packages for a fanuc in this case. I have sourced and built the workspace (using catkin build). I have chosen the fanuc_m16ib20 robot (it was random choice) and I have made the moveit package like in instructions for [the moveit_setup_assistant](https://ros-planning.github.io/moveit_tutorials/doc/setup_assistant/setup_assistant_tutorial.html). At the end of the package generation in setup_assistant I was offered the URDF file for the made configuration, I have copied it and saved it under mypackage/urdf path. After this I have added the Gazebo plugin to the URDF file

> ```
> <gazebo>
> ```

```
    <plugin name="gazebo_ros_control" filename="libgazebo_ros_control.so">
        <robotNamespace>fanuc_m16ib20</robotNamespace>
    </plugin>
</gazebo>
```

Also I wanted to fix(anchor) the robot to the world and I added this to the beginning of the URDF file:

```
  <link name="world"></link>
  <joint name="fixed" type="fixed">
     <parent link="world"/>
     <child link="base_link"/>
  </joint>
```

Next thing I have done is, added the namespace `fanuc_m16ib20` to the controllers, controller spawner and controller manager. I have modified the `demo_gazebo.launch` file to do this and `controller.yaml` files accordingly.

After this changes all it was left to do is to try and run the `demo_gazebo.launch`file, but after running it Gazebo and Rviz are started but the robot in the Gazebo is moving by itself. Since it is connected to the RViz I can see the same behaviour in the RViz, with the exception, in RViz there robot joints stay connected.
When I run `rostopic list` or `rosservice list` I can see topics and controller manager under the same namespace.

topics:

```
> /fanuc_m16ib20/fanuc_arm_controller/command
/fanuc_m16ib20/fanuc_arm_controller/follow_joint_trajectory/cancel
/fanuc_m16ib20/fanuc_arm_controller/follow_joint_trajectory/feedback
/fanuc_m16ib20/fanuc_arm_controller/follow_joint_trajectory/goal
/fanuc_m16ib20/fanuc_arm_controller/follow_joint_trajectory/result
/fanuc_m16ib20/fanuc_arm_controller/follow_joint_trajectory/status
/fanuc_m16ib20/fanuc_arm_controller/state
/fanuc_m16ib20/joint_states
```

services:

```
/fanuc_m16ib20/controller_manager/list_controller_types
/fanuc_m16ib20/controller_manager/list_controllers
/fanuc_m16ib20/controller_manager/load_controller
/fanuc_m16ib20/controller_manager/reload_controller_libraries
/fanuc_m16ib20/controller_manager/switch_controller
/fanuc_m16ib20/controller_manager/unload_controller
```

I have these errors and a few warnings:

```
[ERROR] [1573735342.035351047]: name, joints, action_ns, and type must be specifed for each controller

[ERROR] [1573735343.777676683, 0.001000000]: No p gain specified for pid.  Namespace: /fanuc_m16ib20/gazebo_ros_control/pid_gains/joint_1
[ERROR] [1573735343.779464187, 0.001000000]: No p gain specified for pid.  Namespace: /fanuc_m16ib20/gazebo_ros_control/pid_gains/joint_2
[ERROR] [1573735343.781116227, 0.001000000]: No p gain specified for pid.  Namespace: /fanuc_m16ib20/gazebo_ros_control/pid_gains/joint_3
[ERROR] [1573735343.783848394, 0.001000000]: No p gain specified for pid.  Namespace: /fanuc_m16ib20/gazebo_ros_control/pid_gains/joint_4
[ERROR] [1573735343.785975603, 0.001000000]: No p gain specified for pid.  Namespace: /fanuc_m16ib20/gazebo_ros_control/pid_gains/joint_5
[ERROR] [1573735343.797053511, 0.001000000]: No p gain specified for pid.  Namespace: /fanuc_m16ib20/gazebo_ros_control/pid_gains/joint_6
```

After solving the PID errors, building and launching again, I have one error:

```
[ERROR] [1574279938.204750673] [/move_group] 
[ros.moveit_simple_controller_manager.SimpleControllerManager]: No controller_list specified.
[ INFO] [1574279938.204892173] [/move_group] [ros.moveit_simple_controller_manager.SimpleControllerManager]: 
Returned 0 controllers in list
[ INFO] [1574279938.231018920] [/move_group] [ros.moveit_ros_planning.trajectory_execution_manager]: Trajectory 
execution is managing controllers
```

I found this very strange because from the list of topics I have the action server `/fanuc_m16ib20/fanuc_arm_controller/`
up and running and I have loaded the `controller_list` parameter on the parameter server.
After `rosparam get /controller_list` i get this:

```
- action_ns: follow_joint_trajectory   
 default: true   
 joints: [joint_1, joint_2, joint_3, joint_4, joint_5, joint_6]   
 name: fanuc_arm_controller 
 type: FollowJointTrajectory
```

This looks like the robot offers a FollowJointTrajectory action service, like it can be seen in the topic list, but moveit simple controller manager is still complains about the controller_list for some reason.
Does anyone knows what could have caused this?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/337642/spawned-robot-in-gazebo-is-moving-by-itself-(moveit!)/) by [marko1990](https://answers.ros.org/users/49364/marko1990/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2019-11-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok after hours of trying to understand what went wrong I have finally figured it out. The problem was not in the `/controller_list` parameter, it was because the parameter `move_group/controller_list` was missing and since I am using namespaces I have a `controller_list.yaml`as a separate `.yaml` file and I have loaded it in the `ros_controllers.launch` right after `ros_controllers.yaml`.

I thought that was all, but controllers have to be loaded under moveit also it is not enough just to load them under `ros_control` like I explained before, by this I mean I should have loaded `controller_list.yaml` file under the `move_group` namespace in a `move_group.launch` also. This means and I am assuming you made `yourrobot_pkg` with the moveit_assistant and you are using an `urdf` file created by moveit_assistant (after that you have added your namespaces if neccesarry):
in yourrobot_moveit_pkg start demo_gazebo.launch which should have this structure (mostly made by moveit):

> ```
>  different arguments declarations
>         .
>         .
>    gazebo.launch     
>       -> robot_description(urdf) to param server
>       -> spawns robot_description param in gazebo
>       -> ros_controllers.launch //ros_controllers and the controller_list to the param server
>    node joint_state_publisher
>    node robot_state_publisher
>    move_group.launch
>       -> different arguments declarations
>                                  .
>                                  .
>       -> trajectory_execution.launch.xml // load launch file under the `move_group` namespace
>                 -> different arguments declarations
>                                           .
>                                           .
>                          $(arg moveit_controller_manager)_moveit_controller_manager.launch.xml
>                                //loads moveit_simple_controller_manager on the parameter server 
>                                // load controllers on the parameter server
>                                   ros_controllers.yaml
>                                   controlller_list.yaml
> ```

Basically you need to think about your namespaces and I think the first loading of the `controller_list.yaml` in the ros_control could be taken out. Because it is important that the `controller_list` parameter is loaded under the `move_group` namespace.

---

Originally posted by [marko1990](https://answers.ros.org/users/49364/marko1990/) with karma: 61 on 2019-11-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0